# Here is a recursive program that gives wrong output, please help me

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I saw a program like this in a book:

Here is a program: print out integers. Here you have a positive integer n and want to print it out. The name of the program is printOut(n). Suppose there is an existing routine that will only process a single number and output it to the terminal .The routine that prints a single digit is named printDigit.

The program requires the use of recursion.

The sample code given in the book is:

```java
    public static void printOut(int n)
    {
        if (n >= 10)
        {
            printOut(n / 10);
        }
        else
        {
            printDigit(n % 10);
        }
    }
```

The code of the routine `printDigit` is not given in the book. After thinking, I think the program should be like this:

```java
public class PrintOutTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Print.printOut(76234);
    }
}

class Print
{
    public static void printOut(int n)
    {
        if (n >= 10)
        {
            printOut(n / 10);
        }
        else
        {
            printDigit(n % 10);
        }
    }

    static void printDigit(int n)
    {
        System.out.print(n); //7
    }
}
```

But when I run it, the terminal only outputs the number 7.

I took a closer look and found that the printDigit method only entered once, which should be the problem. But I don’t know how to modify it. Please ask if you can help me. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to modify it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to emit the digits from left to right (most significant to least significant).

It is easier to get the rightmost digit (this is `n % 10`) than the leftmost one (this is `n` divided by... some power of `10`). So the recursion will take this shape:

```
To print out a number:
  if longer than one digit
    recurse on the number without its rightmost digit
  print out the rightmost digit
```

and more precisely,

```
To print_number n:
  if n > 9
    print_number n / 10
  print_digit n % 10
```

Answer (score 0):

`PrintDigit` is only called when n is less than 10, so that happens only once...

You need to also call `PrintDigit` when you make the recursive call. So:

```
    public static void printOut(int n)
    {
        if (n >= 10)
        {
            printOut(n / 10);
        }
        printDigit(n % 10);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration, the number goes diving by 10
for your example 76234 > 7623 > 762 > 76 > 7 and now 7 is smaller than 10 so the recursive function called the print method and 7 gets printed.

below is an example to fix the problem.

```
class Print
{
    public static void printOut(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0) return ;
        printOut(n / 10);
        printDigit(n % 10);
    }

    static void printDigit(int n)
    {
        System.out.print(n); //7
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your printDigit function is OK. Just dont wrap it with else block:

```java
    public static void printOut(int n)
    {
        if (n >= 10)
        {
            printOut(n / 10);
        }
        printDigit(n % 10);
    }
```

And also, I personally don't prefer to learn any programmin language from books cause they gets outdated and writers often suck at algorythms. And once they make a mistake there is no chance to republish a book but in Github there is issues, pull requests, comments, and code is editable also forkable.